# Use another table's data in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a event table and a transaction log. 
And I want count each event's total revenue by one sql. 
Could anything tell how to do this.
please be ware there will be more than 100,000 logs in transaction table.

event_table:

```
Event_id | start_date |  end_date  
------------------------
11111  |  2013-01-04   |   2013-01-05 
11112  |  2013-01-08   |   2013-01-10
11113  |  2013-01-11   |   2013-01-12
11114  |  2013-01-15   |   2013-01-18
11115  |  2013-01-19   |   2013-01-21
11116  |  2013-01-22   |   2013-01-24
11117  |  2013-01-26   |   2013-01-29
```

transaction_log:

```
    id | name    | time_created |  Cost
    ------------------------
    1  | michael | 2013-01-04   |   1
    2  | michael | 2013-01-08   |   4
    3  | mary    | 2013-01-11   |   5
    4  | john    | 2013-01-15   |   2
    5  | michael | 2013-01-19   |   3
    6  | mary    | 2013-01-22   |   2
    7  | john    | 2013-01-26   |   4
```

---

I tried to use the sql like following, but it does not work.

```
select 
      event_table.id,
      ( select sum(Cost)
        from transaction_log
        where date(time_created) between transaction_log.start_date and transaction_log.end_date ) as revenue
from event_table
```

Comment: You need dto describe _how_ it does not work, what you were expecting and so forth.

Comment: I was going to sum one table's data by using the time period stocked in another table.  I've never realized that I can use " join on (xx between xx) ". It is solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing because the fields `start_date` and `end_date` are from `event_table` but you're stating them as `transaction_log.start_date` and `transaction_log.end_date`. This will work:

```
select 
      event_table.id,
      ( select sum(Cost)
        from transaction_log
        where date(time_created) between event_table.start_date and event_table.end_date ) as revenue
from event_table
```

There is no need to cast `time_created` as date (`date(time_created)`) if it is already of date data type. Otherwise, if time_created is timestamp or timestamptz, then for performance you may want to consider doing:

```
select 
      event_table.id,
      ( select sum(Cost)
        from transaction_log
        where time_created >= event_table.start_date::timestamptz and time_created < (event_table.end_date+1)::timestamptz ) as revenue
from event_table
```

Also for performance, when executing a query like the one above, PostgreSQL is executing a subquery for each row of the main query (in this case the `event_table` table). Joining and using GROUP BY will generally provide you with better results:

```
select e.id, sum(l.Cost) as revenue
from event_table e
join transaction_log l ON (l.time_created BETWEEN e.start_date AND e.end_date)
group by e.id
```

Comment: I used the last query,  it works perfectly.   I've never used the query like
 a join b on (b.bb between a.aa and a.ab)
it is really amazing, thank you!

Comment: @YuanGao If satisfactorily answered, please tag the question as answered so it no longer attracts people willing to help.